# counter count is not increasing when clicking a button

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i made a react class component but it wont increase in value when i try to click button element. any way i can made it to work?

```
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);




function App() {
  return (
    <div>
    <MyButton/>
    </div>
  );
}


class MyButton extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { count: 0 };
  }

  incrementCounter() {
    this.setState(state => ({
      count: state.count + 1
    }));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>Counter: {this.state.count}</p>
        <button onClick={this.incrementCounter}>
          Increment
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

i expect for the button the increase in number accordingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the button click event handler is not correctly bound to the incrementCounter method

You can do:

```
class MyButton extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = { count: 0 }
    this.incrementCounter = this.incrementCounter.bind(this) // <-- Binding `incrementCounter`
  }

  incrementCounter() {
    this.setState((state) => ({
      count: state.count + 1,
    }))
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>Counter: {this.state.count}</p>
        <button onClick={this.incrementCounter}>Increment</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

And here is a more clean and functional version:

```
const MyButton = () => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0)

  const incrementCounter = () => setCount(count + 1)

  return (
    <div>
      <p>Counter: {count}</p>
      <button onClick={incrementCounter}>Increment</button>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: thankyou. but what is the reason that i need to add `bind()` method?

Comment: In React class components, you must use `bind(this)` on event handle methods to ensure that the correct this context is available when the event is triggered. Without binding, `this` will refer to the event target instead of the component instance.

Comment: You're already using a function component for `App` @UltraRocket - Yosvel's second code would probably be more useful for you.